# Script to logout user and perform background task

Tags: macos, scripting, authentication

I'm trying to find a way when a user logs in the system to automatically log off and perform a background script.

Specifically I will need to remove the local user account but keep the home folder in place. This will only need to be done once but I'm not sure of the best approach. The purpose of logging in once is to capture the account that is used, however as long as they are logged in  the account cannot be deleted.

All of the system are either Mac OS X 10.5.8 OR 10.6.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this using .bash_logout script.  From bash's manual page:

> When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

ur question is ambigious....

Automatically logging off can be done by loginhook....make one that sets a timer to certain time and then gives the log off command....

If u make the account a guest account... its contents will automatically be deleted once the user logs out... 
So i would suggest that make a guest account, 
using sudo command, make a loginhook....that will automatically logout user after the timer expires and since it is a guest account, all information will be deleted.,..

only thing left is capture...for that use a usb, run a script that copies the concerned folders to usb...
hope this helps

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity. I don't think making guest accounts will help. See there already exist local user accounts on these systems. We ultimately want to switch to network accounts and that is why we would like transfer the data out of the users current account and move it to the network account. Now technically, we aren't copying the data back to the server so in a sense, the data is still remaining on the box just in a different place. I'm not sure if that makes anymore sense. I think your idea of the loginhook might help us so I really appreciate the response.